# python and ctypes accessing c++ classes with nested structures

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a shared library and two header files. I was able to use the library by creating bindings using `swig`. However, the `swig` version is quite slow and I didn't manage to include support for `numpy` arrays. I am now trying to call functions of the library from Python using `ctypes`.

First header contains an `extern "C"` block which exports 3 functions through macros (which are not available to me). The simplified version of the header looks like this:

```
...

class Foo;
typedef Foo* FOO_HANDLE;

#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#   error "C++ Compiler only"
#endif

extern "C"
{
    APIPROTOTYPE_EXT( MakeAlgo, FOO_HANDLE, (void) );

    APIPROTOTYPE_EXT( DestroyAlgo, void, ( FOO_HANDLE ) );

    APIPROTOTYPE_EXT( AlgoProcess, void, ( FOO_HANDLE, StructOne *, StructTwo *) );
}
```

Normally, the first function `MakeAlgo` returns a pointer to an instance of the `Foo` class, the second function `DestroyAlgo` destroys the instance, and the third function `AlgoProcess` takes two structures as an input and modifies some of their values in-place.

The second header contains definitions of `StructOne` and `StructTwo` and some constants. `StructTwo` contains several nested structures.

In Python, I rewrote all the structures contained in the second header using `ctypes.Structure`. I don't post all the code here but here's an example how I defined a nested structure:

```
class StructTwo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("foo", StructFoo),
                ("dummy8", c_short)]

class StructFoo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bar", c_uint),
                ("reserv1", c_uint),
                ("reserv2", c_uint)]
```

Then my Python code looks like this (assuming the structures are in a `structures.py` file):

```
from ctypes import *
from structures import StructOne, StructTwo

libfoo = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(path/to/so/library)

makeAlgo = libfoo.MakeAlgo
makeAlgo.restype = c_void_p
makeAlgo.argtypes = []

destroyAlgo = libfoo.DestroyAlgo
destroyAlgo.restype = None
destroyAlgo.argtypes = [c_void_p]

submit = libfoo.AlgoProcess
submit.restype = None
submit.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(StructOne), POINTER(StructTwo)]

handle = makeAlgo()

one = bar.StructOne()
two = bar.StructTwo()

submit(handle, byref(one), byref(two))
print(two.foo.bar)  # unsigned int, should output 1, got 196611000 instead

destroyAlgo(handle)
```

After creating a pointer to the `Foo` class, submitting the inputs, I check some of the values in one of the structures and it doesn't match the expected result. For instance, I know that one of the fields are set only to 0 or 1 by the library, but I get some weird results, like 196611000.

Does anybody knows what is wrong (maybe someone had similar problem)? Can it be the way I defined the structures? Or maybe it is a pointer to the C++ class which is not handled correctly?

<s>**EDIT**</s>

I managed to solve the initial problem. It appears that the way I define the structures was not correct. Instead of the above code, the nested structures should be passed by reference:

```
class StructTwo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("foo", POINTER(StructFoo)),
                ("dummy8", c_short)]

class StructFoo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bar", c_uint),
                ("reserv1", c_uint),
                ("reserv2", c_uint)]

# Then to initialize the nested structure
foo = StructFoo()
two = StructTwo(pointer(foo))  # has to be pointer() not byref()
```

However, now to access the `StructFoo`'s fields, I have to do:

```
print(two.foo.contents.bar)
```

In actual code I might have up to 4 nested levels. Is there a more elegant way to access their fields then:

```
two.foo.contents.baz.contents.qux.contents.field_value
```

Comment: Does it work if called from a *C* (*C++*) app?

Comment: In general, it looks right, but the structure definitions could be wrong and the C definitions weren't provided.

Comment: @CristiFati, yes, the C++ version works as expected, so does the swig wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My edit was incorrect.

The problem was that some of the structure were bit-field structures, specifying the width of each field solved it:

```
class StructTwo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("foo", StructFoo),
                ("dummy8", c_short)]

class StructFoo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bar", c_uint, 1),
                ("reserv1", c_uint, 8),
                ("reserv2", c_uint, 16)]
```

[Bit-field structures in ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions).